# How to Graph the Function $f(x,y)=2(x+y)+(x−y)^2−(x+y)^3$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

I'm trying to graph the function $f(x,y)=2(x+y)+(x−y)^2−(x+y)^3$ and I'm seeking guidance on how to go about it. Here's what I've done so far:

First, I've defined a range for both $x$ and $y$, specifically, from $-5$ to $5$.

Second, I've calculated the values of the function for various $(x,y)$ pairs within this range.

For example: if $(x,y)=(2,3)$ then:

$f(2,3)=2(2+3)+(2−3)^2−(2+3)^3$

$=2(5)+(−1)^2−(5)^3$

$=10+1−125$

$=−114$

Third, I've created a set of points $(x,y,f(x,y))$ to represent these calculated values:

$(2,3,−114)$

$(1,1,−1)$

$(0,0,0)$

$(−1,−1,−1)$

$(−2,−3,−114)$

Now, I'd like to create a three-dimensional graph with $x$ and $y$ on the $xy$-plane and $f(x,y)$ as the $z$-coordinate. However, I'm not sure how to proceed further or if my approach is correct.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to create this graph?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: you are on the right track. When using pen and paer, you just have to pick more right points and look for patterns: are there any symmetries between x and y?  are there any values of x and y that simplify the expression (i.e., (0,0), (1,1), (2,2))?

Short of that I'd recommend a computer: python is really handy for this sort of thing!

Comment: @ning Thank you for your response!!! Are there specific analytical methods or guidelines, analogous to those used for graphing single-variable real functions, for graphing functions of two variables?

Comment: You got me thinking and I'm going to look if anyone has ever written anything on this - because previous to computers, I feel like someone might have written something on the topic.

Though the other Idea that came to mind is to compute derivatives! If you can figure out in what ranges the partial derivatives change values that may help you get a feel for what the grapho should look like.

Comment: @ning Thank you very much for your thoughtful response and for considering this question. I appreciate your willingness to explore the topic further. I'm also intrigued by the idea of computing derivatives to gain insights into the behavior of the graph. I'll look into that approach as well. If you happen to come across any existing literature on this topic, I'd be very interested in learning more. Once again, thank you for your assistance!

Comment: One more quick idea that came to mind: go plane by plane and stictch them together. Along with looking for changes in partial derivatives, hold one of the variables constant and see how the other two vary. For example, hold $z = 0$ explore how the xy plane looks there, then change $z=1$, explore xy-plane, and repeat.
Info about changes in partial derivates along with that may help speed up the process.

Comment: Great idea! I'll definitely look into this approach, along with examining changes in partial derivatives. Your insights have been incredibly helpful, and I truly appreciate your guidance in tackling this problem.

Comment: Notice that in this example whenever $x+y$ is a constant, the function becomes parabolic. So if you decompose the $xy$ plane into parallel lines of the form $x+y=c$ and imagine the vertical planes cutting the $xy$ plane along those lines, the intersection of those planes with the function surface will be parabolas whose parameters will be determined by the value of $c$.